# suppress warnings from windows live mail untrusted cerficate ssl

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, certificate

Hi we have setup our own mailserver using ssl.
Each time I start up windows live mail, in comes up with an annoying message that

"The server you are connected to is using a security certificate that could not be verified"

Is there some way to add this cerficate such that we wont see this message on every program start.

When using firefox (our mailserver can also be webbased) or thunderbird, I get the option to allow the certificate without asking again.

I'm perfectly aware that we can buy a certificate that will make the message go away, but this we dont want to do.

Thanks

edit:

I have succesfully imported the certificate such that I can access the website without complains using ie, however the problem still persists in windows live mail.

Answer (score 2):

Windows Live Mail uses the same certificates as IE. Try importing your certificate into IE.

Answer (score 0):

You can import into your browsers (all the browsers you use to access mail) the public key of the CA certificate you built and used to sign the mailserver certificate. Place it in the authority section.

This will do the same as if you had a paid certificate like verisign but the difference is that well known paid certificates are already pre-loaded in most browsers.

This way when the SSL certificate expires, you'll create a new one using the same CA to sign it and you will have to do nothing on the browsers as they will accept the signing key of the new certificate.

Comment: obs: you can add the CA public key to firefox and thunderbird too so you will not be using an exception approval like you are when accepting and configuring to stop asking.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the live mail account. Then install the certificate in the trusted root authorities. Finally add again the account. For some reason if you install the certificate after adding he account it will not work.